# Why would numpy.count_nonzero(arr) not work with assigned axis value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a two dimensional array and would like to count values by row. Even though I assign an axis value, axis = 1, method still returns single integer.

```
x = rng.randint(10, size=(6,3))

x
Out[120]: 
array([[3, 3, 8],
       [8, 8, 2],
       [3, 2, 0],
       [8, 8, 3],
       [8, 2, 8],
       [4, 3, 0]])

np.count_nonzero(x)
Out[121]: 16

np.count_nonzero(x, axis=1)
Out[122]: 16
```

I tried copying an example directly from the docs page and got the same results.

```
np.count_nonzero([[0,1,7,0,0],[3,0,0,2,19]], axis=1)
Out[123]: 5
```

Where expected:

```
array([2, 3])
```

I using Python 3.6

Any ideas what might be keeping the method from returning an array of counts from across rows?

Comment: Works for me.  What _numpy_ version are you using?

Comment: I'm using '1.11.3'. I'll try updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the v1.12 docs:

```
axis : int or tuple, optional
    Axis or tuple of axes along which to count non-zeros.
    Default is None, meaning that non-zeros will be counted
    along a flattened version of ``a``.

    .. versionadded:: 1.12.0
```

So this axis parameter is newish.

`count_nonzero` is used by `nonzero` (`where`) to determine the size of the arrays it needs to allocate to return results.  For that purpose it doesn't need the axis parameter.  It just needs to be fast and simple. If developers saw that use as its main justification, it could explain why `axis` is a late addition.

Comment: Right there for me to see. Thanks for pointing out what I should have caught.